# Springs and Hooks

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, puzzle

Okay,

I am dealing with a problem, that I can't seem to solve. A little help ?

**Problem:** Given a wooden line of length M which has n hooks and the positions of these hooks are given as an array ( 0 < p < M ). There is a spring attached to each hook and each spring has a metal ball at the other end. All balls are of the same radius, R and the same mass m. The springs have the same stiffness coefficient.
How do we find the optimum position of the balls such that the springs and the system is in equilibrium ? The metal balls are not allowed to go before or after the line. i.e ends of the balls cannot be < 0 or > M. It is possible to have multiple hooks at the same position in the array.

**Assumptions**: The given array is always valid.

You can ignore the vertical stretch and only consider the stretch of the spring in the horizontal directions. The problem can be seen as 1D in nature then.

**Limits:** O(nlogn) solution or better is sought here.

**Example:** M = 10, array = [ 4, 4 ], R = 1 ( Diameter is 2 ), optimum ball position = [ 3, 5 ]

*What I've tried so far:*

- take one hook/ball at a time, create clustors if two balls hit each other. Place them symmetrically at centroid of the hooks. *Bottleneck* O(n^2) since balls keep hitting each other
- Put all balls at the complete centroid of the hooks. return max of 3 sub-problems recursively..
  a) balls that are being stretched left, b) balls being stretched right, c) balls in middle of these. *Bottleneck* The 3 subproblems may have overlaps and getting the overlaps good seems awkward. 
  [image]

Comment: This seems underspecified. Are the hooks' positions given, or do we get to decide where they go? What about the springs' lengths and force constants, and the balls' masses?

Comment: I think a visualization would help a lot here.

Comment: Why is the first method `O(n²)`? If you sort the balls (or better the clusters), you can find intersecting ones by a variant of binary search (`O(log n)`). And you need to do this `n` times. So overall complexity should be `O(n log n)`.

Comment: @Nico every time 2 balls hit, they make a cluster of 4. 2 clusters of 4 each make 8. As the size of the cluster keeps growing, more and more balls start getting hit. In the worst case this can get O(n^2).

Comment: But you just need to check a cluster's bounds. If a ball lies within these bounds, you just have to sort it into the cluster (`log n`) and recalculate the positions (`n`).

Comment: How do u solve for R=1, array: 1,3,5,7,9,11,12,12,12  M = 15 ?
then see 1,1,1,1, 8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,..x25 times, 50. Im not sure I've explained well. But the point is that the order in which things will clash is not known and it can keep growing.

Comment: Am I the only one who can't visualize what is being described here? A simple diagram would go a long way in clarifying things.

Comment: Are you sure about the physics? Will the balls always distribute around the hooks' average?

Comment: No. the average is the first approximation. I do more refinements on it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sort of binary search to find the correct position of each of the balls.

1. Start the balls next to each in order of their connections the farthest left each can go.
2. Calculate the amount of space you have for the balls to move (the distance from the right-most ball to the right edge), and use half of this as your starting increment.
3. Calculate the net force on each ball from the spring, its neighbors, and the edges.
4. Move each ball the increment in the direction of the net force on it, or keep it where it is if there is no net force.
5. If the increment is below the precision you want or all balls had no net force on them, stop.  Else, Divide the increment by 2 and go to step 3.

Comment: :-) Even i thought of something like that. 

The problem with this is that imagine the hooks are concentrated to the right but not the extreme right.. Then initially the force will be quite high.. Causing a lot of movement. The force signs will change.. and the whole this will kinda oscillate. I would then need multiple iterations to converge on the optimum solution. Wouldn't I ? Or have I not understood completely ?

Comment: @KshitijBanerjee Yes, this solution is an iterative approach that will get you closer and closer to the correct solution with each pass over steps 3-5.  Also note that the magnitude of the net force does not affect the distance you move the balls, as only the direction of the net force matters.  For example, if there was 8 units of freedom, you'd first move the balls 4 in the net force direction, then 2 in the next pass, then 1, and so on until you get to your desired accuracy.